# SharePoint - Obtaining all files from a web

Tags: sharepoint, file

I have a requirement wherein I have to obtain all the files of a web recursively (i.e. traversing through the folders and sub folders) and display them for the user through SP Object Model.

This has to be security trimmed, in the sense, if the user doesn't have sufficient privileges to view or open the file, then that file shouldn't be taken into account. Is it possible to obtain all the files without looping through each and every document library, folders and sub folders?

Also, I don't want the default document libraries like web part gallery, master page gallery,etc to be listed out. Any insights on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content Query Web Part can get you most of the way there.  Out-of-the-box you could set this up to show all files (based on a content type or content type category) from a site collection.  You could even filter to remove system files although that might be a little tricky to get the filters right.

If that doesn't get you far enough, then you could write a web part that extends the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart` class.  You could override the Filters (by setting the `FilterField1`, `FilterType1`, `FilterOperator1`, `FilterValue1`, etc).

The security trimming should happen for you by the default behavior of the ContentQueryWebPart.  The Web Part and Master Page galleries will get filtered out based on your content type settings so you shouldn't have to worry about those.